# Windows Docker location of file env.conf

Tags: docker, windows, configuration

I found that on Linux you can configure some settings inside file:
`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/env.conf` .

I am wondering where I can find it in windows wsl?- purpose is to set those two fields:
`Environment="BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=1073741824"`

`Environment="BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SPEED=10240000"`

Answer (score 1):

It will be in

```
    C:\Users\<UserName>\. wslconfig
```

if you're using WSL2.

More information here:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/